# How to determine the authentication method used by the website?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, http-authentication

I want to know the authentication method used by the site so that I can pass the appropriate parameter in requests.get method.

```
requests.get(url, auth = authmethod)
```

Is there anyway to get the authmethod.

Answer (score 0):

Make the request without attempting authentication, receive a 401 response, and read the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

In a certain sense, Requests seems to handle this for Digest, but that's because reading the challenge values is part of the flow. For Basic auth, the user agent can just remember the credentials for a particular (root URL, realm) pair.

Comment: With the server side rendering website, almost all calls are `200 ok`. The `401` is handled at the server side of front end.